# JTable split header Disable Sorting

Tags: java, sorting, header, jtable, jxtable

Currently every header contains the name of the column and ocassionally a combo box below it.  Whenever the combo box is clicked the jtable automatically sort.  Is there a simple way to disable sorting for just the combo box clicks while preserving the rest of the header to sort on click.

I have been suggested JXTable but am fearful that it will cause more problems than it would fix.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312953/how-can-you-disable-all-sorting-code-in-jtable-in-1-6 gives some information but not exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying... well I kind of am. Could you offer some code of the project?

Comment: the code is sort of spread out (should be cleaned up but that is another issue). I want to maintain the sort feature on the rest of the header but ignore sorting for the combo box. Not quite sure how to override the JTable's sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public class SortFilterTableHeaderUI extends BasicTableHeaderUI {

    private Component filteredComponent;

    @Override
    protected MouseInputListener createMouseInputListener() {
        return new MouseInputHandler() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (!filteredComponent.contains(e.getPoint()))
                    super.mouseClicked(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Other option is override `JTAbleHeader.columnAtPoint(Point point)` and return -1 if the combo contains the point.